# Push Data to Android app from Local Server

Tags: android

I have created Android Based Meeting Room Screens, which fetch data from the server hosted in the Intranet and get Data.

For the very first time these screens need to be configured and I was looking for Mechanism wherein I can push the Meta Data into these screens but my problem is that these screens and server is on the Intranet

Comment: Huston we have a problem

Comment: provide us some code problem